# Difference between an inverse and re-arranging?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

This is a pretty simple question but one that I've had trouble with for a long time.  What I would like to know is this: what exactly is the difference between an inverse and a rearrangement of a formula?

For example, let's say I have the formula

$y = 2x$

I can form the inverse by switching $x$ and $y$ and solving for $y$ to get

$y = \frac{x}{2}$

However, I can also simply re-arrange the first equation to get

$x = \frac{y}{2}$

My question is, functionally (no pun intended), what is the difference between these last two equations?  Aren't both now mapping from the co-domain to the domain?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you think these two functions are doing? Given a number $a$, where does $y = x/2$ send $a$? Where does $x = y/2$ send it?

Comment: Note completely sure I follow?

Comment: I now notice you said "formula" instead of "function" in your question. Do you mean to ask about the inverse of a function?

Comment: The initial function would be $f(x) = 2x$.

Comment: So that function sends a number $a$ to the number $2a$. Presumably, when you write $y = x/2$, you mean the function which sends a number $a$ to the number $a/2$, which is indeed the inverse of your original function. What do you mean by $x = y/2$? Where does it send $a$?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean by the second part of your question?  It would take as an argument $a$ and also produce $\frac{a}{2}$.

Comment: My point is that functions are not the same thing as equations. Equations like $y = x/2$ and $x = y/2$ can't be interpreted as functions until you specify what your independent variable is. It sounds like you're just switching variable names, and using $y$ as the independent variable in the last equation (which is very uncommon).